# Conditional Probability and (in)dependent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am looking at a data set that asks the question did you receive Healthcare. The possible responses were Yes, A member of their family did, or Both. My first question is are these responses independent? I think they are, but it may not be due to later findings.

I would like to find the number of responses that said Yes. But clearly the people that said Both have some people who said Yes. So I thought well in order to figure out the total number of people that said Yes, $TY$. We have:

$$P(TY)=P(Y)+P(\text{Yes}\mid\text{both})$$

Well, $P(Y)$ is easy to solve. But $P(\text{Yes}\mid\text{both})=P(Y\cap \text{both})/P(\text{both})$. This is were the independence question comes into play. If they are independent, then $P(TY)=2P(Y).$ If not then how does one solve for $P(Y\cap\text{both})$? Also I believe these two 'Yes' are different in a sense.

I know that $P(Y\cap\text{both})=P(Y)+P(\text{both})-P(Y \cup \text{both})$. But what is $P(Y \cup \text{both})$?

If anyone of this is incorrect or seems wrong. Please let me know. If somebody knows a way to go about it, then please tell me.

Comment: First Question: "Both" is true if and only if "yes" and "a member of my family did" are true. So these responses are not independent.

Comment: This depends on whether the question was check-all-that-apply or check-only-one-box style.

Comment: $\text{Did you receive health care?  (Check all that apply) }\boxed\checkmark\text{ Yes }\boxed\checkmark\text{A family member did}
\\[2ex]\text{Did you receive health care? (Check only one) }{\huge\Box}\text{ Yes }{\huge\Box} \text{ A family member did }\boxed\checkmark\text{ Both }$

Comment: I do not have the original responses like that, but I am assuming that shouldnt matter for what you are talking about @GrahamKemp.